# how to create query in SOLR with distinct + subselect (select in ...)

Tags: select, solr, distinct, subquery

QUESTION below:

Data structure in SOLR:

```
<field name="id" type="string" required="true"/> 
<field name="session_id" type="string" required="true"/> 
<field name="action_type" required="true"/> 
<field name="error_msg" required="false"/>
```

(all fields have:  indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false")
only 'error' field is not required (can be null).

There is equivalent table in oracle:

```
TABLE SOLR_TEST
  (
    ID          NUMBER NOT NULL ,
    SESSION_ID  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
    ACTION_TYPE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
    ERROR_MSG   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  );
```

there is sample data (the same for SOLR and Oracle)

```
ID SESSION_ID           ACTION_TYPE          ERROR_MSG          
-- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
 1 00001                SELECTED_ACTION                           
 2 00001                SELECTED_ACTION                           
 3 00001                OTHER                                     
 4 00002                A2                   ERROR_001            
 5 00002                OTHER                                     
 6 00003                SELECTED_ACTION      ERROR_002            
 7 00004                A1                   ERROR_001            
 8 00005                A2                                        
 9 00005                SELECTED_ACTION                           
10 00005                SELECTED_ACTION      ERROR_003            
11 00006                SELECTED_ACTION                           
12 00006                OTHER                ERROR_004
```

**QUESTION:**

How to create in SOLR query which will return:
all `session_id` which have specified `action_type` but never happen specified `action_type` with non empty `error_msg`

or equivalent of this query in Oracle:

```
select distinct session_id 
    from SOLR_TEST 
    where action_type='SELECTED_ACTION' 
    and not session_id in 
      ( select session_id 
        from SOLR_TEST 
        where action_type='SELECTED_ACTION' 
              and error_msg is not null
      );
```

result for this query is:

```
SESSION_ID         
--------------------
00001                
00006
```

e.g. SOLR query like this is **not** working:

```
http://solrhost/solr/collection/select?rows=1&q=-(error_msg:[*+TO+*]+AND+action_type:SELECTED_ACTION)&wt=xml&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=session_id&facet.zeros=false&fq=action_type:SELECTED_ACTION
```

// EDIT /////////////////////////////////////

real schema looks like this:

```
<schema name="elogging" version="1.5">
  <fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="action_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="session_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="error_msg" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  </fields>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <types>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true"/>
  </types>
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="uniq-fields">
    <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <lst name="fields">
        <str>id</str>
      </lst>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
</schema>
```

// EDIT 2 //////////////////////

SOLR query is not working as I expect - this SOLR query returns something like:

```
select distinct session_id 
from SOLR_TEST 
where action_type='SELECTED_ACTION' 
and error_msg is null;

SESSION_ID         
--------------------
00001                
00005                
00006
```

**Value '00005' is wrong** because there is a row:

```
10 00005                SELECTED_ACTION      ERROR_003
```

// EDIT 3 ////////////

this SOLR query also not working (the same issue as for previous):

```
http://solrhost/solr/collection/select?rows=1&q=action_type:SELECTED_ACTION+AND+-{!join+from=session_id+to=session_id}error_msg:*+AND+action_type:SELECTED_ACTION&wt=xml&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=session_id&facet.zeros=false
```

// EDIT 4 ///////

*fixes schema - 'error_msg' is indexed*

// EDIT 5 /////

There you have sample data for SOLR:

```
id,session_id,action_type,error_msg
1,00001,SELECTED_ACTION,
2,00001,SELECTED_ACTION,
3,00001,OTHER,
4,00002,A2,ERROR_001
5,00002,OTHER,
6,00003,SELECTED_ACTION,ERROR_002
7,00004,A1,ERROR_001
8,00005,A2,
9,00005,SELECTED_ACTION,
10,00005,SELECTED_ACTION,ERROR_003
11,00006,SELECTED_ACTION,
12,00006,OTHER,ERROR_004
```

and

result from SOLR for this data and query `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection3/select?rows=1&q=-(error_msg:[*+TO+*]+AND+action_type:SELECTED_ACTION)&wt=xml&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=session_id&facet.zeros=false&fq=action_type:SELECTED_ACTION`:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">30</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="facet.zeros">false</str>
<str name="facet">true</str>
<str name="indent">true</str>
<str name="q">
-(error_msg:[* TO *] AND action_type:SELECTED_ACTION)
</str>
<str name="facet.field">session_id</str>
<str name="wt">xml</str>
<str name="fq">action_type:SELECTED_ACTION</str>
<str name="rows">1</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="4" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">1</str>
<str name="session_id">00001</str>
<str name="action_type">SELECTED_ACTION</str>
<long name="_version_">1449881246216749056</long>
</doc>
</result>
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="session_id">
<int name="00001">2</int>
<int name="00005">1</int>
<int name="00006">1</int>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
<lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: Could you post your schema.xml as is? This would help to tackle errors there. Otherwise what types do `action_type` and `error_msg` have?

Comment: all is 'string' - sorry I missed this info.

Comment: I added schema - it is SOLR 4.4.0

Comment: SOLR query returns also documents/rows where *some* sessions_id are corelated with not null values for error_msg. - adding this info to description of question.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of tricky, because as far as I know(and I would be very happy if someone could prove this wrong) - it's not possible to reuse *parts* of query result in another query(e.g. filter query or nested query).

So, here is as close as I can get currently:

**Query**:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/stack19588325/select?q=action_type%3A%22SELECTED_ACTION%22&fq=%7B!tag%3Ddt%7Daction_type%3ASELECTED_ACTION+AND+error_msg%3A%5B*+TO+*%5D+AND+_query_%3A%7B!join+from%3Dsession_id+to%3Dsession_id+v%3D%24qq%7D&rows=0&wt=xml&indent=true&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.field={!ex=dt%20key=nonfilter_session_id}session_id&facet.field=session_id&qq=-error_msg:[*%20TO%20*]
```

**Result**:

```
<response>    
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">0</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="qq">-error_msg:[* TO *]</str>
    <str name="q">action_type:"SELECTED_ACTION"</str>
    <arr name="facet.field">
      <str>{!ex=dt key=nonfilter_session_id}session_id</str>
      <str>session_id</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="indent">true</str>
    <str name="fq">{!tag=dt}action_type:SELECTED_ACTION AND error_msg:[* TO *] AND _query_:{!join from=session_id to=session_id v=$qq}</str>
    <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
    <str name="rows">0</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
    <str name="facet">true</str>
    <str name="_">1382878844535</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
</result>
<lst name="facet_counts">
  <lst name="facet_queries"/>
  <lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="nonfilter_session_id">
      <int name="00001">2</int>
      <int name="00005">2</int>
      <int name="00003">1</int>
      <int name="00006">1</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="session_id">
      <int name="00005">1</int>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <lst name="facet_dates"/>
  <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

So, as you see here, we have two different facet results:

- **nonfilter_session_id** - This shows those "session_id" which don't have error_msg. The count - is overal count of session_id records.
- **session_id** - This shows those "session_id" which both have AND don't have error_msg (this is the case with 00005). The count - is cound of session_id with error_msg.

So, if there won't be any better choice - you can make an intersection of those two sets, and there will be only those session_id's that are expected.